# Pipe from third party debugger to own app

Tags: named-pipe

Third party debugger (specifically, IAR C-Spy) has a Macro language that can help debug an application. This language allows you to read and write to files.

There doesn't appear to be a way of integrating to the debugger or macro language outside of the IDE.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to write an application that uses a pipe, and somehow get the macro language to open this pipe, as an inter-process communication. The macro language doesn't support pipes, but it does support files.